# how we are acessing adjacent nodes of node with empty vector list

Tags: c++, graph, c++17

when we do mp[node] = first , in below code means now our node pointing to node with empty vector then how we can acess its adjacent nodes in for(auto adj: curr -> neighbors) {}.
is node reference dosent changed when we ddo mp[node]  = first;
question link->https://leetcode.com/problems/clone-graph/

```
/*
// Definition for a Node.
class Node {
public:
    int val;
    vector<Node*> neighbors;
    Node() {
        val = 0;
        neighbors = vector<Node*>();
    }
    Node(int _val) {
        val = _val;
        neighbors = vector<Node*>();
    }
    Node(int _val, vector<Node*> _neighbors) {
        val = _val;
        neighbors = _neighbors;
    }
};
*/




class Solution {
public:
    unordered_map<Node* , Node*> mp; 
    
    Node* cloneGraph(Node* node) {
        if(node == NULL) 
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        
        Node* first = new Node(node -> val, {}); 
        mp[node] = first;
        
        queue<Node*> q; 
        q.push(node); 
        
        while(q.empty() == false) 
        {
            Node* curr = q.front(); 
            q.pop(); 
            
            for(auto adj: curr -> neighbors) 
            {
                if(mp.find(adj) == mp.end()) 
                {
                    mp[adj] = new Node(adj -> val, {}); 
                    q.push(adj); 
                    
                }
                
                mp[curr] -> neighbors.push_back(mp[adj]); 
            }
        }
        
        return mp[node];
    }
};
```

Comment: `node` is the node from the original graph - that one has neighbors. `first` is the node from the new graph - it doesn't have neighbors yet, the algorithm will add them eventually. `curr` points to some node in the original graph, with neighbors. As you walk through this algorithm, keep reminding yourself which pointers refer to nodes in the original graph being traversed, and which to nodes in the new graph being built. `mp` maps original nodes to corresponding new nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ class attributes are constructed automatically by the class constructor.  So, you do not need to set the neighbours attribute in your constructors.

```
// Definition for a Node.
class Node {
public:
    int val;
    vector<Node*> neighbors;

    /** Construct with no neighbors
    * @param[in] _val node value, defaults to 0
    */
    Node(int _val = 0)
    : val( _val )
    {}

    /** Construct with  neighbors
    * @param[in] _val node value
    * @param[in] _neighbors
    */
    Node(int _val, vector<Node*>& _neighbors)
    :  val( _val )
    , neighbors( _neighbors )
   {}
};
```

In your code you have

```
unordered_map<Node* , Node*> mp;
```

This looks very strange!  Can you explain what you are trying to do here?  This seems to be a map with both the key and the value equal to each other, which is unnecessary.  Perhaps a set would do what you need.